# Django. Redirecting user after login

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie in Django and I need your help.

I'm building my app on class-based views. For login I using default `django.contrib.auth.models.User` class and one-to-one relationship for `UserInfo` class for storing additional information(like profile photo and so on):

**models.py**

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    avatar = models.FilePathField()
```

After login succeed I want to pass `UserInfo` data to home page(defined as `DetailView`). So currently I have something like this:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',      Index.as_view(), name='index'), #Returns page with login form.
    url(r'^login$', Index.as_view(), name='login'), #Proceed login form and redirects to homepage.
    url(r'^home/id(?P<pk>\d+)$',  login_required(Home.as_view(), login_url='/'),  name='home'),
)
```

**index.py**

```
#Login proceed here
class Index(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    success_url = '/home/id'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/home/id', pk = user.id)
        else:
            return redirect('/', {'error' : 'Incorrect login or password'})
```

**home.py**

```
class Home(generic.DetailView):
    model = UserInfo
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Could you please help me to understand how it should work?
And how I should get `UserInfo` data inside my `home.html` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass data in URL redirects, because this is inherently safe and prone to all kind of exploitation ([Content Spoofing vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Spoofing)).

Instead, you should pass data over redirect using [Django sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/). Particularly, in the case of the success/error messages, [Django messages framework is handy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).

```
from django.contrib import messages

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Incorrect username or password")
        return redirect('/')
```